# How do I check if I have a cache-related issue?

Tags: c#, .net, web, webforms, browser-cache

I think I have a bug that is related to cache.
But, when I go to Dev Tools > Application > Cache. There is nothing there.

Can it be a different type of cache? Like Response cache for example.

If so, how do I verify that a problem is related to caching.

To explain a bigger picture, I log in to the website using SSO. On a certain page, I make a change, submit a request, page refreshes and changes are not done.

When I do not log in using SSO, everything is fine.

I suppose that I will add this in aspx.cs

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

and in aspx, I will add this

```
<%@ OutputCache NoStore="True" Duration="1" VaryByParam='*' Location="None" %> 

$.ajax({
    cache: false
    //rest of ajax
});
```

Even if it fixes the issue, I want to know why is there a problem with a cache.
Question is, how do I diagnose such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For websites (or web apis) there are a lot of solutions if you want to implement caching. You have the client-side caching that happens in the browser. You can monitor this cache using the (F12) DevTools.

Then you have a cache layer that you can add on the hosting level (IIS for example). There is the response cache like you already mentioned in your question.

And finally there is (let's call is) 'manual' cache that allows you (as a developer) to take full control of your caching solution.

According to the infomation provided in your question you probably did everything to rule the first caching option out. This doesn't mean that a different form of caching is not there in your solution. You're going to have to dive in the code to find code or calls to a caching solution.